# Send data from onSharedPreferenceChanged() to another UI Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, singleton, android-preferences, android-sharedpreferences

I play Loop Background Music in app, I use SoundPool.
Also I use PreferenceFragment (and sharedPreferences of course), and UI checkbox “*Background Music On/Off*”.

As soon as the user remove/set the UI checkbox from Preference Fragment, background music should be to stop/start play it immediately.

**Question**:

How to send data from PreferenceFragment from onSharedPreferenceChanged() to another UI fragment immediately (see the diagram)?
Thx.

[image: diagram]

**UPD**
Problem solved.

Make an Object (which directly controls the sound) as Singleton.
Then from onSharedPreferenceChanged called SoundPool_pause_method directly.

[image]

Perhaps this is not true in terms of architecture.

I (quickly) read a lot of information:
Using MediaPlayer in a service,
AsyncTask (I already know that it is not appropriate),
Executor,
ThreadPoolExecutor,
FutureTask,
HandlerThread.

Comment: Use [EventBus](https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus). It is a library to fire events from any component to component in the app.

Comment: Or send internal broadcast (if you are in search of a quick solution)

Comment: If both fragments are attached to Mainactivity and should react on the same sharedPreferencesChange, why not implementing the listener it in the activity which knows both fragments.

Answer (score 1):

If you are in search of a quick solution then you can try firing custom broadcasts.

You can check tutorial [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_broadcast_receivers.htm).  Your `MainUIFragment` will be `BroadcastListener` which will listen to specific custom event broadcast which can be fired by `PreferenceFragment` when intended.

Declaring in manifest

```
 <receiver android:name="MyReceiver">
         <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="some.identifier.string">
            </action>
         </intent-filter>
  </receiver>
```

Custom Receiver to handle event broadcasts

```
public class MyReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver{
   @Override
   public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
      Toast.makeText(context, "Intent Detected.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
   }
}
```

Firing event from

```
public void broadcastIntent(View view){
      Intent intent = new Intent();
      intent.setAction("some.string.identifier"); sendBroadcast(intent);
   }
```